# angular material dialog pass dynamic function when clicked on save

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

**dialog.ts**

```
export class DialogComponent {
    constructor(private service: RestService, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {
    }

    no() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

    save() {
        const url = 'https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users'; 
        const options = {headers: HttpHeaders, params: HttpParams};

        const getResp: any = this.service.Get(url, options);       
        this.dialogRef.close();

    ///THIS save() FUNCTION HARDCODED, BUT I WANT TO MAKE RESTCALL DYNAMICALLY WHEN ANYONE CLICKS SAVE BUTTON IN DIALOG
    }

}
```

**dialog.html**

```
<mat-dialog-actions>

    <button class="mat-raised-button"
            (click)="no()">
        no
    </button>

    <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary"
            (click)="save()">
        save
    </button>

</mat-dialog-actions>
```

**component1.ts**

```
 getUsers() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent,
        dialogConfig, passSomeRestCall-1-FunctionSomehow());  
  }
```

**component2.ts**

```
 getEmployees() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent,
        dialogConfig, passSomeRestCall-2-FunctionSomehow());  
  }
```

Above 2 components have to make use of Dialog Component dynamically, currently above save() hardcoded with some restcall, but actually rest call needed when clicked on save() for both above components. So, in short, save() button should happen dynamic restcall based on the component.

Could anyone please help me on above, I am very new to angular.

**EDIT:**

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      this.service.makeRestCall(this.items[i]);
    }
```

**How do I pass above for loop logic in dialog component? I should be able to do some business logic dynamically inside save() based on component like below**

```
save(){
   dynamicMethod() // this should be passed somehow from a component
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Comment: can anyone pls look into above?

Comment: use a switch statement?

Comment: @docholiday sorry, I didn't get you, please understand my query. I should be able to pass some business logic in some dialog component, any idea?

Comment: still looking for an answer.

Comment: still looking for an answer.....

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to pass the callback method. It should be part of modal's parent.
Only you have need is to set @Output into the modal with type EventEmitter. Like:

```
@Output() save = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

On Save button just implement:

```
handleSave: void {
  this.save.emit(true);
}
```

Parent will listen this @Output and handle it properly.

```
dialogRef.componentInstance.save$.subscribe((res) => {
    // Here is your business logic 
  }
);
```

So:

1. If after processing is everything OK, you can use dialogRef in your parent and close the modal (dialogRef.close()).
2. If something is wrong, modal will not be closed.

Using this way, our modal will be free of business logic. Especially important for generic modals, like confirmation, user inputs, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your url , options etc as data in your dialog component and pass it in save function like below.

UserComponent

```
 openDialog(): void {
    let ApiDetails = {
      url: 'https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users'
    }
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent,
      {
        data: ApiDetails
      });
  }
```

DialogComponent

```
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
  }

  no(){
    this.dialogRef.close()
  }

  save(){
    console.log(this.data) // this will have url and other details whatever you send from calling parent
  }

}
```

Comment: HI, I just added something in my query above, could you please check once, my question is: How do I pass for loop logic in dialog component?